# How can I concatenate dynamic values with the flatten vector in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to increase the accuracy of CNN by computing some dynamic values such as Hu moments of the images during the training phase and then feed them to the fully connected layer with the flatten vector as shown in the image of my model:

[image]

I want to compute Hu moments for each image in the dataset then after the flatten operation, I want to concatenate the values of the Hu moments with the fatten vector and feed it to the fully connected layer.

This is the model I'm using (Tensorflow Keras):

```
layer1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3),padding="same", activation='relu')(inpx) 
layer2 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer1) 
layer3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer2) 
layer4 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer3)
layer5 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5, 5),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer4)
layer6 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer5) 
layer7 = Dropout(0.5)(layer6) 
layer8 = Flatten()(layer7) 
layer9 = Dense(250, activation='sigmoid')(layer8) 
layer10 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(layer9) 

model = Model([inpx], layer10) 



model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), 
              loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
              metrics=['accuracy']) 

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=500) 
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

The dataset I'm using is MNIST handwritten digits.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And why do you use fully connected layers and not CNN?

Comment: My question is how can I feed dynamic values for each image like Hu moments to the fully connected layer alongside the flatten vector

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I don't know what the Hu moments and the Extend and Soidty are, but I'm assuming they're 1dimensional:

```
# image = tf.Tensor
@tf.function
def calc_hu(image):
   """ calculate hu """
   hu = ... 
   return hu

class HuLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
      return calc_hu(inputs)

@tf.function
def calc_extend(image):
   """ calculate extend """
   extend  =  ...
   return extend

class ExtendLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
      return calc_extend(inputs)


layer1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3),padding="same", activation='relu')(inpx) 
layer2 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer1) 
layer3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer2) 
layer4 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer3)
layer5 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5, 5),padding="same", activation='relu')(layer4)
layer6 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer5) 
layer7 = Dropout(0.5)(layer6) 
layer8 = Flatten()(layer7) 
layer8_ = tf.layers.keras.concatenate([layer_8, HuLayer()(tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)(inpx)), ExtendLayer()(tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)(inpx))]) 
layer9 = Dense(250, activation='sigmoid')(layer8_) 
layer10 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(layer9)
```

I didn't test this code but it should set you on your way. Hope it helps you enough to get going!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207506/discussion-on-answer-by-frederik-bode-how-can-i-concatenate-dynamic-values-with).